# sed: replace a match with the same match and add more text

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a file called `config.properties` that contains the following text:

**cat config.properties**

```
// a lot of data
com.enterprise.project.AERO_CARRIERS = LA|LP|XL|4M|LU|4C
//more data
```

and my goal is keep the same data but adding more. For this example i want to add to the assignment of this variable `|JJ|PZ` results in:

**cat config.properties**

```
// a lot of data
com.enterprise.project.AERO_CARRIERS = LA|LP|XL|4M|LU|4C|JJ|PZ
//more data
```

The command that I've been using for this is :

```
 sed 's/\(com\.enterprise\.project\.AERO_CARRIERS\s*\=\s*.+\)/\1\|JJ\|PZ/g' config.properties
```

But this doesn't works. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: It works for me. Your sed might not support `\s` - try `[[:blank:]]` instead.

Comment: Oh wait, I was lying, it didn't work. `.+` is not in sed basic regular expressions; you either have to use `..*` or `.\+` (GNU extension of BRE) or `sed -r` (GNU) or `sed -E` (BSD sed).

Comment: Thanks!! the error was using `.+` instead  `.\+`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to use stream-editors like `sed`, just use the native *text editor*, `ed` from `UNIX`-days for in-place search and replacement. The option used (`-s`)  is `POSIX` compliant, so no issues on portability,

```
printf '%s\n' ",g/com.enterprise.project.AERO_CARRIERS/ s/$/\|JJ\|PZ/g" w q | ed -s -- inputFile
```

The part `,g/com.enterprise.project.AERO_CARRIERS/` searches for the line containing the pattern, and the part `s/$/\|JJ\|PZ/g` appends `|JJ|PZ` to end of that line and `w q` writes and saves the file, in-place.

Comment: Nitpick: the portability depends on the POSIX compliance of the different implementations of a tool. The mere existence of a POSIX spec doesn't guarantee portability - if I use a feature defined in the POSIX spec and a tool isn't conformant, I _do_ have portability problems.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Really appreciate the fact, it kind of became a colloquial  thing with all the `POSIX` compliance wordings I've seen around. Thanks for clarifying it! Re-wording it now!

Answer (score 1):

`\s` and `+` are not POSIX compliant:

- you can match spaces and tabs with `[[:blank:]]` and whitespace characters(including line breaks) with `[[:space:]]`.
- `.+` can be replaced with `.\{1,\}` or `..*`

And you don't need to use backreference here, use `&` instead to output lines matching your pattern:

```
sed 's/^com\.enterprise\.project\.AERO_CARRIERS[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*.\{1,\}/&|JJ|PZ/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match first:

```
sed '/com\.enterprise\.project\.AERO_CARRIERS\s*\=\s*.\+/ s/$/|JJ|PZ/g' config.properties
```